# Dask with docker not showing anything in dask's dashboard

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dask

I'm using Dask with Docker Compose locally on my machine (OSX Catalina 10.15.17).  My docker-compose file is the same as [this](https://github.com/dask/dask-docker/blob/master/docker-compose.yml) except that I added a volume in the notebook container.
I can correctly access the dashboard at the default address `localhost:8787` but when I launch some tasks, i.e. working with xarray or something like this:

```py
import dask.array as da
x = da.random.random((1000,1000,10), chunks=(1000,1000,5))
y = da.random.random((1000,1000,10), chunks=(1000,1000,5))
z = (da.arcsin(x) + da.arccos(y)).sum(axis=(1,))

z.compute()
```

Nothing appears in the dashboard:

[empty dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/THRbj.png)

I have tried with both launching with the LocalCluster

```py
from dask.distributed import Client, LocalCluster
cluster = LocalCluster()
client = Client(cluster)
client
```

then using the Jupyter lab Dask extension on the lefthand side to launch the cluster from there.

Do you have any suggestions? Am I missing something?

Cheers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've run through the same workflow that you describe and have a couple of pointers.

In order to connect to the Dask cluster you need to create a [Client object](https://distributed.dask.org/en/latest/client.html).

So before you run any code in your notebook you first need to run

```py
from dask.distributed import Client
client = Client("tcp://scheduler:8786")  # We could also omit the address because it is set in the `DASK_SCHEDULER_ADDRESS` environment variable
```

Then running your Dask array code will execute on the cluster. However it is also worth noting that this is such a small amount of work it completes almost immediately and the dashboard shows nothing for me. However if I head to the profile page I can see a profile of the work executed, so it definitely ran there.

[image: Dashboard profile plot]

If I increase the array sizes to `da.random.random((10_000,10_000,10), chunks=(1000,1000,5))` then I see activity on the dashboard.

[image: Dashboard task graph]

---

My final comment here is that the `docker-compose.yml` file you are using is actually part of the build pipeline for the Dask Docker image and is not actually intended for folks to use to run Dask. Although it does work. You may find this simpler config easier to work with.

```yaml
version: "3.1"

services:
  scheduler:
    image: daskdev/dask
    hostname: dask-scheduler
    ports:
      - "8786:8786"
      - "8787:8787"
    command: ["dask-scheduler"]

  worker:
    image: daskdev/dask
    hostname: dask-worker
    command: ["dask-worker", "tcp://scheduler:8786"]

  notebook:
    image: daskdev/dask-notebook
    hostname: notebook
    ports:
      - "8888:8888"
    environment:
      - DASK_SCHEDULER_ADDRESS="tcp://scheduler:8786"
```

Comment: Thank you very much indeed for your help, Jacob!

Comment: Jacob, what is the difference of creating a client with the command you wrote above instead of using the "New" button in the "Dask" tab on the left-hand side of the notebook? In the latter case, the dashboard seems not to show anything..

Comment: Clicking the "New" button creates a new cluster, typically a `LocalCluster` unless you've modified your default config. Creating a `Client` object connects you to an existing cluster.